# Need information on MongoDB security config options - MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have replica set of MongoDB v4.2 with 3 servers running. In my mongod.conf file, until now I have below options configured for security config section. Authorization is not enabled as per config file, but if I want to access mongo shell then I need to authenticate myself using username and password, not sure how if authorization is not enabled.

```
security:
  keyFile: /var/lib/mongo/mongokey
```

Now, I want to include below 2 new fields into config file under security section. So what is difference between mongokey file provided in keyFile section and below clusterAuth keyFile or sendKeyFile values. If I use keyFile or sendKeyFile under clusterAuth, what will happen ? Mongodb documentation is not clear enough to find difference for these options.

```
security:
  keyFile: /var/lib/mongo/mongokey
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile or sendKeyFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a keyFile enables user authentication.

> Enforcing internal authentication also enforces user access control.

[Update Replica Set to Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/)

Comment: Thank you @john for the help, now I got the idea about user access control. Now, I just want to understand that if we want to use clusterauth:keyFile then whether clusterauth uses same keyfile which we provide in keyFile: option.

Comment: @sandy_ws Are you using x509 certificates? If not you do not need to set clusterAuthMode. **clusterAuthMode** is used to select **keyFile** or **x509** certificates when internal auth is using or will be upgraded  to x509. If set to **sendKeyFile**, the file contents selected by **keyFile** is used. These links provides more details: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/upgrade-keyfile-to-x509/ and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/

Comment: Thanks @john, I got the required information from your comments.

Comment: Yes @john, I have accepted the answer.